# How to execute IIFE script file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iife

I have a very specific scenario.

I have a javascript file called `ApplicationExtension.js` and inside, it has an **IIFE** structure as:

```
const ApplicationExtension = (function() {
    ...
    ...
    return {
        functionName : functionToExpose
    }
})();
```

I have another file `script.js` and inside it, I want to access the `ApplicationExtension` so that I can execute `ApplicationExtension.functionName()`

I will be running `script.js` in a node environment and `ApplicationExtension.js` is being executed in a browser environment.

I have tried,

```
const App = require('./js/extended/application_extension');
console.log(App)
```

which as expected is an `{}` object since there is no `export` in `ApplicationExtension`.

**Points to Note**

1. `ApplicationExtension.js` is currently being executed in browser and `script.js` is executed in 
    Node.js.
2. I can't use `export` in `ApplicationExtension.js` as there are quite a lot of dependencies on it and it is practically impossible to change everything to **module** based project because of legacy reasons.

Comment: what's wrong with using `module.exports`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: export the ApplicationExtension from ApplicationExtension.js like
exports.ApplicationExtension instead of const ApplicationExtension.js

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't because `module.exports` will not work in the browser where `ApplicationExtension.js` needs to be executed

Comment: @HubballiHuli doing that will mean I'll have to change the way `ApplicationExtension` is being used in other script files. All the other script files use it as `ApplicationExtension.functionName()` which is available globally in the browser

Comment: oh, you tagged `node.js` ... so this is browser code?

Comment: @JaromandaX Currently, the file `script.js` runs in `node.js` and `ApplicationExtension.js` runs in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading it with FS and converting it into function using new Function ().

Comment: That is one possible solution. I would have to remove the `const ApplicationExtension` supply that to the `new Function()` and then call the methods.

If nothing else works, I'll go with this